# Non-clustered foreign key index recommendation

Tags: sql-server, indexing, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012

I have several tables in my database that are parent child relationships.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cntnr_header] 
(
    [cntnr_id]            [dbo].[uid]     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_cntnr_header] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cntnr_id] ASC),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cntnr_content] 
(
    [cntnr_content_id]  [dbo].[uid]       NOT NULL,
    [cntnr_id]          [dbo].[uid]       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_cntnr_content] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([cntnr_content_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_cntnr_content_cntnr_header] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([cntnr_id]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[cntnr_header] ([cntnr_id]),
);
```

Currently as you can see there is not an index on the foreign key `cntnr_id` in the table `cntnr_content`. I ran the tuning wizard and I actually saw it suggest a non-clustered index be added for both `cntnr_content_id` and `cntnr_id` on the table `cntnr_content`.  I don't really understand this because `cntnr_content_id` is already a clustered index.  Why would it recommend an index like this?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_cntnr_content_7_821577965__K1_K2] ON [dbo].[cntnr_content]
(
    [cntnr_content_id] ASC,
    [cntnr_id] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would think that I probably should add a non-clustered index just on `cntnr_id` in this table.

Is there a recommended practice for this scenario? Should I always add certain indexes with relationships like this?

A lot of the queries are either joining these two tables together on `cntnr_id` or doing a select on `cntnr_content` by specifying the `cntnr_id`.  This is also an update/delete heavy table.  Updates and deletes are always done on the primary key (`cntnr_content_id`).

Comment: An index on a foreign key can often be useful, but be very careful about using terms like "always" and "never." In this type of case it depends a lot not on the structure of the table itself or the relationships between them, but how the data is queried.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've added some additional information at the bottom that describes generally how this table is queried but I'm also curious as to why the tuning advisor would suggest a non-clustered index on both of those columns.

Comment: Ok, so if your question is, "Will an index on this foreign key in this scenario be useful?" The answer is, "Probably, yes." You'll need to test. If the question is, "Will indexes on all foreign keys always be useful?" The answer is no.

Comment: Also, are you missing the PK constraint definition from the header table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I accidentally left it out.  It's in the question now.

Comment: Hard to comment on the usefulness of the recommended index because we can't see the actual query (or queries) that generated the recommendation. It might not be coming from the query you think it's coming from.

Comment: @AaronBertrand For this table specifically let's assume that my last paragraph holds true.

Answer (score 5):

Clustered indexes are stored physically on disk as a binary tree. Typically they are great for *read* heavy workloads.

The reason the profiler is suggesting that you not use a non-clustered index on the cntnr_content table is because you typically will access data on that table using the foreign key.

In this situation, the clustered index on your primary key is not useful as the data is spread across the disk in a way that is hard to find when using the foreign key. That's why it suggests using non-clustered indexes.

Changing to non-clustered indexes allows the database to choose an on disk format that is more optimal for lookups via the foreign key. Of course, doing so will affect the speed of lookups on the primary key, so it's a trade off - you get more speed in one case, but sacrifice some speed in another case.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "changing to non-clustered indexes" - the clustered index may very well be useful for other queries, and shouldn't be removed IMHO. A non-clustered index can be added without removing any existing indexes.

Comment: you're right, it may be useful for other queries. I was just explaining the logic that the profiler used to reach it's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The non-clustered index on cntnr_id is obviously for the foreign key so that if you were to attempt to delete one from the header table, it would not require a table scan.

Also for your primary use case where you are looking up by header.

Having a non-clustered index by itself on cntnr_content_id really doesn't make much sense.  A composite non-clustered index on both (cntnr_id, cntnr_content_id) (in that order) might make sense if it's covering because it will be narrower than the clustered index.

Comment: Well there are a lot of updates/deletes done on that table by cntnr_content_id as well. I would think it would still be beneficial in these cases.

Comment: @ColeW Not likely.  It's the first column in the CI and the CI is really what will need to be updated or deleted.  You understand that a table is either a heap or a clustered index?  A clustered index is not something separate from the table.  It describes how the table data is structured in a b-tree based on the clustered index key with the non-key data in the leaves.  Then nonclustered indexes are separate b-trees referring either to the heap bookmarks or the clustered index keys in the clustered index b-tree.